# Evitar valores NaN en dataframe en Python

Tags: python, pandas

Cómo podría evitar los valores NaN a la hora de generar una gráfica con matplotlib en Python? Es decir, no quiero que los reemplace, simplemente que no los tenga en cuenta. Es para generar gráficos de barra y torta solo con los valores válidos de una columna. Me gustaría también hacer lo mismo con una matriz de puntos (x,y)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes eliminarlos, pandas tiene el método `dropna` que elimina todas las filas donde encuentre valores NaN

```
df.dropna( inplace=True )
```

Puedes leer mas de este método [aquí](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)